# Ambiquity while drawing multiple shapes on Jpanel

Tags: java, swing

Th code below has few problems :

1) The polygon joins last and first point itself, should not do itself but user should draw it.

2) The polygons lines disappeared after clicking on other shapes.

```
package Circles;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////PaintDemo
class PaintDemo2 {
 //============================================================= main
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     PaintWindow2 window = new PaintWindow2();
     window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     window.setVisible(true);
 }//end main
}//endclass PaintDemo


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////PaintWindow
class PaintWindow2 extends JFrame {
 PaintPanel2 canvas = new PaintPanel2();
 //====================================================== constructor
 public PaintWindow2() {
     //--- create the buttons
     JButton circleButton = new JButton("Circle");
     circleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             canvas.setShape(PaintPanel2.CIRCLE);
         }});
     JButton rectangleButton = new JButton("Rectangle");
     rectangleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             canvas.setShape(PaintPanel2.Ellipse);
         }});

     JButton polyButton = new JButton("Polygon");
     polyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             canvas.setShape(PaintPanel2.POLY);
         }});

     //--- layout the buttons
     JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
     buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
     buttonPanel.add(circleButton);
     buttonPanel.add(rectangleButton);
     buttonPanel.add(polyButton);

     //--- layout the window
     Container content = this.getContentPane();
     content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     content.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
     content.add(canvas     , BorderLayout.CENTER);
     this.setTitle("Paint Demo");
     this.pack();
 }//end constructor
}//endclass PaintWindow


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// PaintPanel2
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PaintPanel2 extends JPanel implements MouseListener, 
                                        MouseMotionListener {
 //--- Public constants used to specify shape being drawn.          
 public static final int NONE      = 0;
 public static final int LINE      = 1;
 public static final int Ellipse = 2;
 public static final int CIRCLE    = 3;
 public static final int POLY    = 4;

 //--- Variables to store the current figure info
 private int _shape = NONE;
 public int getShape() {
    return _shape;
}

 private int _currentStartX = 0;  // where mouse first pressed
 private int _currentStartY = 0;
 private int _currentEndX   = 0;  // where dragged to or released
 private int _currentEndY   = 0;

 //--- BufferedImage to store the underlying saved painting.
 //    Will be initialized first time paintComponent is called.
 private BufferedImage _bufImage = null;
 private boolean polygonIsNowComplete = false;

 //--- Private constant for size of paint area.
 private static final int SIZE = 600; // size of paint area

 private final Point trackPoint = new Point();
 private Path2D currentShape;
 private ArrayList<Path2D> lstPloys  = new ArrayList<Path2D>();;
 private Point lastPoint;
 private Point currentPoint;
 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ArrayList points = new ArrayList();


 //====================================================== constructor
 public PaintPanel2() {
     setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
     setBackground(Color.white);
     //--- Add the mouse listeners.
     this.addMouseListener(this); 
     this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
 }//endconstructor


 //========================================================= setShape
 public void setShape(int shape) {
     //--- Provided so users can set the shape.
     _shape = shape;
 }//end setShape


 //=================================================== paintComponent
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);

     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;  // downcast to Graphics2D
     if (_bufImage == null) {
         //--- This is the first time, initialize _bufImage
         int w = this.getWidth();
         int h = this.getHeight();
         _bufImage = (BufferedImage)this.createImage(w, h);
         Graphics2D gc = _bufImage.createGraphics();
         gc.setColor(Color.white);
         gc.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); // fill in background
     }
     g2.drawImage(_bufImage, null, 0, 0);  // draw previous shapes

     drawCurrentShape(g2);
 }//end paintComponent


 //================================================= drawCurrentShape
 private void drawCurrentShape(Graphics2D g2) {
     //--- Draws current shape on a graphics context, either
     //    on the context passed to paintComponent, or the
     //    context for the BufferedImage.
     switch (_shape) {
         case NONE  :
                  break;

         case CIRCLE:
                  g2.drawOval(_currentStartX, _currentStartY,
                              _currentEndX - _currentStartX, 
                              _currentEndY - _currentStartY);
                  break;

         case Ellipse:
                  g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(_currentStartX, _currentStartY,
                          _currentEndX - _currentStartX, 
                          _currentEndY - _currentStartY));
                  break;

         case POLY:

                drawPolyGon(g2);
                break;

         default:  // should never happen
                  g2.drawString("Huh?", 10, 20);
                  break;
     }
 }//end paintComponent



private void drawPolyGon(Graphics2D g2) {

    g2.create();
    if (lastPoint != null) {
         g2.setColor(Color.RED);
         g2.fillOval(lastPoint.x - 2, lastPoint.y - 2, 4, 4);
    }
    if (currentShape != null) {
         g2.setColor(Color.RED);
         g2.draw(currentShape);
         if (lastPoint != null && currentPoint != null) {
              g2.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 64));
              g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(lastPoint, currentPoint));

         }
    }
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (Path2D shape : lstPloys) {
         g2.draw(shape);
    }
    g2.dispose();

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


//===================================================== mousePressed
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    _currentStartX = e.getX(); // save x coordinate of the click
    _currentStartY = e.getY(); // save y
    _currentEndX   = _currentStartX;   // set end to same pixel
    _currentEndY   = _currentStartY;
 }//end mousePressed

 //===================================================== mouseDragged
 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

  _currentEndX = e.getX();   // save new x and y coordinates
    _currentEndY = e.getY();
     this.repaint(); 
     // show new shape
 }//end mouseDragged

 //==================================================== mouseReleased
 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
     // This will save the shape that has been dragged by
     // drawing it onto the bufferedImage where all shapes
     // are written.
    _currentEndX = e.getX(); // save ending coordinates
     _currentEndY = e.getY();

     //--- Draw the current shape onto the buffered image.
     Graphics2D grafarea = _bufImage.createGraphics();
     drawCurrentShape(grafarea);

     this.repaint();
 }//end mouseReleased


 public void mouseMoved   (MouseEvent e) {

     if (currentShape != null) {
          currentPoint = e.getPoint();
          repaint();
     } else {
          currentPoint = null;
     }


 }
 public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e) {}
 public void mouseExited  (MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
     if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
         if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
              Point p = e.getPoint();
              lastPoint = p;
              if (currentShape == null) {
                   currentShape = new Path2D.Float();
                   currentShape.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
              } else {
                   currentShape.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
              }
              repaint();
         } else if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
              currentShape.closePath();
              lstPloys.add(currentShape);
              currentShape = null;
              lastPoint = null;
              repaint();
         }
    }


 }
}
```

Comment: For polygon you have to click a point then drag your mouse till you do next ( single) click

Answer (score 3):

Paint cycles are stateless, that is, the contents of the graphics are not passed from one cycle to another.

You are required to re-paint the entire contents of component on each paint cycles.

You've attempt to implement a double buffer solution, but instead of passing the graphs context of the buffer, you've passed the graphics contents supplied  to you by the paint system.  If you passed the graphs context of the buffer to the `drawCurrentShape` method, it might solve your problem (and eliminate the need to cache all the shapes)

**UPDATED**

So, in your `paintComponent` method of your `PaintPanel2` component, you are creating a `BufferedImage`, but you are not painting the components to it...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;  // downcast to Graphics2D
    if (_bufImage == null) {
        //--- This is the first time, initialize _bufImage
        int w = this.getWidth();
        int h = this.getHeight();
        _bufImage = (BufferedImage)this.createImage(w, h);
        Graphics2D gc = _bufImage.createGraphics();
        gc.setColor(Color.white);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); // fill in background
    }
    g2.drawImage(_bufImage, null, 0, 0);  // draw previous shapes

    drawCurrentShape(g2);
}//end paintComponent
```

Instead, you should use the graphics context from the buffered image to `drawCurrentShape`

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;  // downcast to Graphics2D
    Graphics2D gc = null;
    if (_bufImage == null) {
        //--- This is the first time, initialize _bufImage
        int w = this.getWidth();
        int h = this.getHeight();
        _bufImage = (BufferedImage)this.createImage(w, h);
        gc = _bufImage.createGraphics();
        gc.setColor(Color.white);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); // fill in background
    } else {
        gc = _bufImage.createGraphics();
    }
    drawCurrentShape(g2);
    gc.dispose();

    g2.drawImage(_bufImage, null, 0, 0);  // draw previous shapes
}//end paintComponent
```

It should be noted that this might create some other issues, but the concept is sound.

Personally, I prefer to keep a `List` of all the shapes and repaint them.  This gives you the ability to select, move, delete, re-order and change all the shapes within the program, as well as provide a type of history ;)

Comment: Hi..Thankyou for the suggestion. As I said you are always been very helpful." If you passed the graphs context of the buffer to the drawCurrentShape method, it might solve your problem (and eliminate the need to cache all the shapes)" Can you please ellaborate it more via program then it will be more helpful.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was helpful a bit but it does not solved any of the issues mentioned above. Thanks for the help. If changes can be done to exact program then it will be very appreciable.

Comment: Remove the reference to the `_bufImage`, store each shape in a `List` and repaint them on each paint cycle.